# Enabling iPhone 6/6+ native resolution on another XCode target

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, iphone-6, launchimage

I have an XCode 6 project and a target where I enabled native resolution for iPhone 6/6+ by adding launch image set and app icon set in asset catalog. It worked fine for the main target but when I made a new target, it still shows scaled version on iPhone 6/6+ no matter what I do. I have done everything including checking target membership of files and asset catalogs for the lite target, but all in vain. Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: I see I have 673 items in Copy Bundle Resources in main target as opposed to 671 items in Lite target. Any way to get the diff of the two item list in one shot ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `xcasset` containing the `launch images`.

You should verify the filename, it happens when you have twice the same image